# Regex take numbers from string c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, list, linq

I want to split the string coordinates this type -54°32'17,420" to list with each number, like [54,32,17,420]. I am using

```
var longitudeSplitted = Regex.Split(longitutdeString, @"\D+")
    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    .Distinct()
    .Select(int.Parse)
    .ToList();
```

and it works in general, but the problem showed up when I have  the coordinate like this

-11°42'42,420"
In this case, Im receiving the list with only 3 numbers [11,42,420].
Where is the problem? I dont really understand this behaviour.

Comment: Remove `Distinct`.

Comment: OMG, of course! Thank You :)

Comment: `"-11°42'42,420\"".Split("°',.\"".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` then you get to keep the +/- (also included the period for cultures that use the period as the decimal separator)

Comment: From goscamp: As @juharr wrote, the Distinct is unnecessary:)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I fail to see why that is not the *answer* to this question. Sure, it was lacking a bit in detail and shouldn't be written as a comment but that is *actually* the answer to this question. Remove the call to `Distinct()`.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the deleted answer. If you like the edit you can simply undelete it. I also took the liberty of adding support for the negative numbers. I see that the examples you give expressly doesn't contain them, you're of course free to simply remove that section of the answer.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen it wasn't me who deleted it. I can only vote to undelete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments on the question, the problem was the call to `Distinct()`.

The example I gave, `"-11°42'42,420"`, contained the number `42` twice and one of those was thus removed by the call to `Distinct()`.

The fixed expression would be this:

```
var longitudeSplitted = Regex.Split(longitutdeString, @"\D+")
    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    .Select(int.Parse)
    .ToList();
```

Additionally, my original regex, `@"\D+"` failed to include the sign of negative numbers. I had to rewrite to using `.Matches(...)` instead of `.Split(...)` to include signs.

The correct expression would thus be this:

```
var longitudeSplitted = Regex.Matches(longitutdeString, @"[-+]?\d+").OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    .Select(int.Parse)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
   var numRegex = new Regex(@"[\+\-0-9]+");
   var numMatches = numRegex.Matches("-11°42'43,440");
```

I kept the +/- in the string (to distinguish east from west) and I changed the numbers to something more unique. You end up with 4 strings in numMatches.Items, each of which is parsable into an int.  It worked with "-11°42'42,420" as well, but I wanted to test it with unique numbers as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helper method that you can use

```
private static List<int> ExtratctCordinates(string input)
{
    List<int> retObj = new List<int>();
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        int tempHolder;
        // Use below foreach with simple regex if you want sign insensetive data
        //foreach (Match match in new Regex(@"[\d]+").Matches(input))

        foreach (Match match in new Regex(@"[0-9\+\-]+").Matches(input))
        {
            if (int.TryParse(match.Value, out tempHolder))
            {
                retObj.Add(tempHolder);
            }
        }
    }
    return retObj;          
}
```

Here is sample call

```
List<int> op = ExtratctCordinates("-54°32'17,420\"");
```